# Grails PUT request with XML

Tags: unit-testing, rest, grails

I have a put request that I am trying to unit test for creating a user object.

Unit Test:

```
    void testPUTXMLResponse() { 
    def mockUser = new User(username:"fred", password:User.encrypt("letmein"), firstName:"Fred", lastName:"Flintstone", middleName:"T", phone:"555-555-5555", email:'fred@fred.com', activationDate:new Date(), logonFailureCount:0)
    mockDomain(User, [mockUser])

    def mockUserXML = mockUser as XML
    mockRequest.method = 'PUT'
    mockRequest.contentType = 'text/xml'
    mockRequest.format = 'xml'
    mockRequest.content = mockUserXML.toString().getBytes()

    controller.create()

    def updatedUser = XML.parse(mockResponse.contentAsString)
    assert updatedUser.id == 1
}
```

Controller Action:

```
    def create = {
    println request.xml
    def user = new User(params.user)
    if(!user.hasErrors() && user.save()) {
        println user.id
        withFormat {
            html { /*render(view:"show", [user:user])*/ }
            xml { render user as XML }
            json { render user as JSON }
        }
    } else {
        println user.errors
        withFormat {
            html { /*render(view:"create", [user:user])*/ }
            xml { render user.errors as XML }
            json { render user.errors as JSON }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the params map is null when the controller action is executed. I have a very similar unit test for POST requests and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Grails natively supports REST, so Grails enforces the HTTP specification for PUT and POST.  One of the rules for PUT is that it needs a full URL, including the ID of the object that is being acted on.  In this case, when creating a new User the ID isn't known until after the request.  Therefore, the full URL isn't known and the PUT request fails.  POST does not have this restriction.  For a more in-depth explanation of PUT and POST, see http://jcalcote.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/put-or-post-the-rest-of-the-story/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue you described is caused by the difference in the Tomcat handles PUT vs. POST requests ([see here](http://www.pubbs.net/201002/grails/21558-grails-user-tomcat-put-method-handling-breaks-restful-web-services-in-12x.html)).  Switch out the tomcat plugin for the jetty and your example should work.